# How do I read the cord_19_embeddings_2020-07-16.csv from the COVID-19 Open Research Dataset Challenge (CORD-19) on Kaggle?

Tags: dataset, visualization, word-embeddings, kaggle

[image: table view of the file in TAD csv viewer]

### What I'm trying to do

I wanted to use the [CORD19 word embeddings csv](https://www.kaggle.com/allen-institute-for-ai/CORD-19-research-challenge?select=cord_19_embeddings_2020-07-16.csv) to map them to certain findings from the rest of the dataset, but as we can see there are no stings in the first column.

The way I know word or sentence embeddings, is what they map a word or a sentence to multiple vectors.
The values in the first column look somewhat like hashes, and they are the main problem I can't use the dataset.

Can somebody give me a pointer on what I'm looking at and how to use them?

I have not found documentation, usage examples or submissions on kaggle that have explained or outlined how this file is supposed to be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, after a lot of digging, I found something in the comment section.

They are document embeddings.

- There is a [github repo](https://github.com/allenai/paper-embedding-public-apis) that specifies an API.
- [Paper on arxiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.07180.pdf)
- [Example usage of a similar approach](https://cord19.vespa.ai/article/32753?tab=1)

[image]

Relevant Comments from the Kaggle Comment section on the Data Update Log for the CORD19 Dataset:

- [Comment 1](https://www.kaggle.com/allen-institute-for-ai/CORD-19-research-challenge/discussion/137474#807864)
- [Comment 2](https://www.kaggle.com/allen-institute-for-ai/CORD-19-research-challenge/discussion/137474#810123)

### Examples how to visualize the embeddings in a Jupyter Notebook:

```py
import pandas as pd
from whatlies import Embedding, EmbeddingSet
#Docs: https://rasahq.github.io/whatlies/api/embeddingset/


#transponse dataframe
sample_df = pd.read_csv('data/cord_embeddings_sample.csv', header=None, delimiter=',', index_col=0).T

def to_ems(df):
    ems_dict = {}
    for columnName, columnData in df.iteritems():
        ems_dict.update({str(columnName): Embedding(columnName, columnData)})
    return EmbeddingSet(ems_dict)

ems = to_ems(sample_df.head(10))
```

```py
ems.plot_correlation()
```

[image]

```py
ems.plot_interactive("ug7v899j","02tnwd4m")
```

[image]

You can even do NLP with the `json`s from the dataset and link them to the embeddings via the `UUID` and `SHA` from `metadata.csv`.

**Example:**

Find words that relate to smoking and color the respective papers:

I created 2 `EmbeddingSet`s where I filtered the embeddings for papers that have smoking-related words in their text body and subtracted their `UUID`s from the list.
Both `EmbeddingSets` can be displayed in the plot.

```py
from whatlies.transformers import Umap

# add 2 embedding sets

emb1 = non_smoking_ems.add_property('set', lambda d: 'non smoking papers')
emb2 = smoking_ems.add_property('set', lambda d: 'smoking papers')

both = emb1.merge(emb2)

#add a clustering transformer that reduces dimensionality (like umap) and visualise them
both.transform(Umap(2)).plot_interactive('umap_0', 'umap_1',color='set', annot=False)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you figured out how to use the embeddings and what to do with it?
I assume it's not really relevant what column 2 to 769 represent individually, but how do I use them? Can I compute the similarity or the MeSH classificaiton with this?

Comment: I used [whatlies](https://spacy.io/universe/project/whatlies) by Rasa to visualise them. I added an example.